# Recover pasted date from Excel which transforms it to an integer like 41884 using Excel or R

Tags: excel

Dates in excel were pasted as values in a data set I received. The original format was:

```
9/2/2014
```

The pasted format was:

```
 41884
```

I need to recover these dates either within Excel or using R. Normally integers are time since the Linux epoch (1/1/1970) or another origin. I have not been able to make sense of this data format, however.

- 41939 is 10/27/2014
- 41974 is 12/1/2014

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter "1" in a cell, and format that as date in Excel, you'll get 01/01/1900. It increments one day per integer from there, so you can deduct your actual date from that point no?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use excel try setting the cell format to Date, the number is the amount of days since 1899-12-31 if that helps you in R.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes this helps a ton. For some reason it seems like it's 12/30/1899 instead because if I do `as.Date(41884,origin="1899/12/31")` I get 9/3/2014 instead of 9/2/2014. Weird.